# Cannot install app for ubuntu 16.04 on 20.04

Tags: 16.04, 20.04, syslinux

Is it possible to install apps coming from ubuntu 16.04 in Ubuntu 20.04?

I cannot install `sgdclient_5.40.935-ubuntu16.04_x86_64` on Ubuntu 20.04.

The error is:

```
dpkg: error processing package sgdclient (--install): dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing: sgdclient
```

Comment: Sometimes yes, sometimes no. There have been a lot of changes from 16.04 to 20.04. Please ask a more specific question if you want a more useful answer.

Comment: Yes. I wan to install sgdclient_5.40.935-ubuntu16.04_x86_64 However I have ubuntu 20.04 The error is:

dpkg: error processing package sgdclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.36.0-1ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.24-1ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.64ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 sgdclient

Comment: If you can find a snap version, will have easier time.  Snaps don't care much which Ubuntu version they are used on, where a deb version is made for specific Ubuntu version.

Comment: In your case, the answer from your output seems clearly "No." Since SGD Client is proprietary Oracle software, Oracle Support might have a different answer. Or you can install using a different method than deb packages...if Oracle has other methods available.

Comment: Please show the full output of package installation - something like `sudo apt-get install ./sgdclient*.deb` .